# Ways to put a method into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So as far as I know, we can put a method inside an array like this :

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.newFunction = function() {
alert("hello");}
```

Are there any possible ways (other than the above) to put methods inside arrays?

Comment: `arr.push( function(){} )`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Functions are just objects. You can put them in an array the same way you put anything else in an array.

Comment: The said method is a method of the array, not an array member, i.e. it's not included in the indexed content of the array.

Comment: @Teemu actually that's what i had been wondering. Expecting some one to reply exactly what you commented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to direct assignment (what you're doing), you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign more than one property/method to a specific array.

It's also possible to add methods to **all** arrays (through inheritance) via `Array.prototype`. You should avoid doing that in libraries, but in your own app code it can be okay with proper testing. If you do it, it's important to make the property *non-enumerable* by adding it with `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "newMethod", {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value() {
        // ...code here...
    }
});
```